# Oracle APEX Export File Format

Tags: oracle-apex

When doing an Oracle APEX application export you need to pick a File Format - UNIX, DOS or Database.

For UNIX or DOS, which environment does this apply to - Browser, Web/App server or database server?

What does the Database option do?  When would I want to use this option?

Answer (score 0):

As Paul said, "Unix" vs "DOS" is merely selecting the eol markers in the exported `.sql` script.

"Database" means the script is stored in your workspace Export Repository.

Answer (score -1):

It determines what's used for the end-of-line markers in the exported script.

- UNIX = `lf`
- DOS = `cr` `lf`

When I selected "Database" then did an export, it didn't save a file to my computer. I can only assume it's done something like save the script in a table somewhere, but I haven't found any documentation so far to help.

For me, I'm doing everything on a Windows PC (exporting and importing) so I always set it to DOS (the database server is UNIX) and I've never had any problems.

Comment: I'm trying to get a technical understanding what these options refer too.